# Reason why resize/thumbnail on PIL.Image doesn't work? Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize a PNG image. 
Worth noting that before the image becomes PNG it is converted from SVG (working without problems).

This is the code:

```
        if format == 'png':
            output = BytesIO()
            svg2png(bytestring=monkey_image.to_str(), write_to=output)
            contents = output.getvalue()
            size = 15, 15
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(contents))
         #  tried both resize and thumbnail, same result
         #  img.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS) 
            img = img.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img.save(output, format="PNG")
            contents = output.getvalue()
            output.close()
        return contents
```

The result I am seeing is that it returns the image in the original size (retures the first defined contents)

Maybe I am not saving it correctly to the output in the second to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending your data to an existing `BytesIO` object. Additional writes to such an object do not replace existing data; writing adds more data to the end of the file:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> out = BytesIO()
>>> out.write(b'123')
3
>>> out.getvalue()
b'123'
>>> out.write(b'456')
3
>>> out.getvalue()
b'123456'
```

You now have binary data for **two** images in a single file, but compliant decoders will ignore trailing data in an image file.

Use a *new, empty* `BytesIO()` object:

```
resized = BytesIO()
img.save(resized, format="PNG")
contents = resized.getvalue()
```

You could also seek to the start of the file and truncate:

```
output.seek(0)
output.truncate()
```

before writing to it again, but just creating a new in-memory file object is clearer and less error-prone.